# Can't update single package with go modules

Tags: go

I have 2 projects with go.mod in root directory.
One is https://github.com/Gohryt/Impossible.go
Next one is something that `require` impossible in go.mod

I made simple commit with renaming a pair of variables.
My second module needs in this variables and I renamed it there too.
But I didn't find any command like `go mod update`, only `go mod tidy` and I can't use new names of variables. I tried `tidy`, but it made nothing. In some guides from internet i found that i should rename version in go mod and then tidy should work, but it has name like `v0.0.0-20210101010359-ec9f21b49366` and i really can't guess what is new name like.

Is there any normal way to update module or i should use old version of dependency every time after first usage?

I tried name version with `latest`, but go mod tidy did nothing again.

Comment: `go get {packageName}` if that doesn't update to latest commit `go get {packageName@hash_of_last_commit}`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If module A requires module B, and your program requires both... You will want to make sure module A requires the correct version of module B. Here's some things I end up doing often to keep everything synchronized how I want it.

**To upgrade modules, first enter the repository...**

upgrade all modules:

```
go get -v -u ./...
```

upgrade a certain module to latest commit:

```
go get -v -u github.com/user/repo@master
```

upgrade a certain module to a certain branch:

```
go get -v -u github.com/user/repo@develop
```

and then type this at the end:

```
go mod tidy
```

commit the changes to your repo, and consider a new tag.

```
git commit -v -a
```

```
git tag v0.0.2
```

```
git push origin branch --tags
```

Then, back to your program repository.. and do the same steps, but make sure your imported modules say the right tags when you run that `-v -u` command.

And make sure that your `go.sum`, `go.mod` files doesn't have extra stuff from old modules.

More info here https://blog.golang.org/publishing-go-modules.

Comment: go: malformed module path "https:/github.com/stripe/stripe-go": invalid char ':'

Answer (score 3):

I would do `go get -u "{package_name}@{git_commit_hash}"`

for e.g., `go get -u "gopack@1fdd851775f2bc513003d46850c56cb77d8e297b"`

-u flag is to update an already installed package.